# How to upload Composer to DirectAdmin (sharedhost)

Tags: laravel, composer-php, directadmin

For my laravel project I see that it is required to have composer on the server. I have downloaded composer to my machine, but I don't know what that means to do it for the server. How can I accomplish this?

Comment: Can you ssh into the server?

Comment: i just learned ssh so im not sure how to do that. Can you explain?

Comment: First you must find out with your hosting if you have ssh enabled.

Comment: Ask your server provider,that's the easiest solution and if you do all you need to do is follow [composer installation - Linux / Unix / OSX](https://getcomposer.org/doc/00-intro.md#installation-linux-unix-osx)